# React Native Google Signin Issue

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I've used https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin package, and followed all steps for IOS installation
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/ios-guide.md

on building, getting these errors

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Authentication", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_cfda8ee8fa73859d0bf2f31187291c07.o)
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_ff169582f48f77717621086d9a33a56f.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_cfda8ee8fa73859d0bf2f31187291c07.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_cfda8ee8fa73859d0bf2f31187291c07.o)
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher_5a0f11df6750429e48d8336f3fabe7c8.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_cfda8ee8fa73859d0bf2f31187291c07.o)
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_ff169582f48f77717621086d9a33a56f.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Keychain", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_cfda8ee8fa73859d0bf2f31187291c07.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_cfda8ee8fa73859d0bf2f31187291c07.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

---

I've tried many solutions but didn't work for this.

Comment: are you found a solution to this problem?